# How to validate format in uploadFile js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, excel

I have a problem, i'm creating a function upload by uploadfile js. if a file isn't excel file, system will display error. how do i implement validate excel format by uploadfile js? this is my source

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var uploadObj = $("#fileuploader").uploadFile({
        url:"php/upload.php",
        fileName:"myfile",
        uploadStr: "Nhập file upload",
        abortStr:"Hủy bỏ",
        uploadErrorStr:"Lỗi khi upload, vui lòng kiểm tra lại",
        sizeErrorStr:"Dung lượng file vượt quá giới hạn",
        autoSubmit:false
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried allowedTypes: 'xls,xslx' ?

also you can try onSelect callback:

```
onSelect: function(files) {

  if (files[0].type != 'application/vnd.ms-excel') {
    throw new Error('Not excel file');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you:

```
$("#fileuploader").change(function () {
     var ext = $(this).val().split('.').pop();
     if (ext != 'give extension here') {
         alert("Please valid file type");
         return false;
     }
});
```